# Combine an expression and a new line in ggplot2 legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm probably asking too much, anyway I would like to create a legend title on two lines, where the first line contains an expression (the greek symbol \Phi, with subscript `10`), and the second line is `[.]`. It should look like this:

[image]

I tried

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg,color=qsec))+
     geom_point()+
     labs(color=expression(atop(Phi["10"]),group("[",.,"]")))
```

But this doesn't print the lower line:

[image]

Can you help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply have a bracket in the wrong place. It should be `atop(something, somethingelse)`

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=wt,y=mpg,color=qsec))+
     geom_point()+
     labs(color=expression(atop(Phi["10"],group("[",.,"]"))))
```

[image]